# Get most commented objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, acts-as-commentable

I'm using [acts_as_commentable_with_threading](https://github.com/elight/acts_as_commentable_with_threading) gem to make users able to comment my blog posts.

What I want to do now is to display most commented posts but I have no idea how to query them (and as far as I know, the gem not provides such method). Can you write me some tips or ideas how to achieve something like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a method that I use to return the top users that have posted the most items. It may help you with your issue. I put this in the Application Helper because it is part of my side navigation bar and will be used on every page in the web application.

```
def top_posters
    User.all(:select => "users.*, COUNT(user_id) as post_count",
       :joins => "LEFT JOIN posts AS posts ON posts.user_id = users.id",
       :group => "posts.user_id",
       :order => "post_count DESC",
       :limit => 5)
end
```

In my view, I have

```
<% top = top_posters() %>
<% for t in top %>
    <li><%= link_to t.username, user_path(t) %>
        (<%= t.posts.public_posts.count %>)</li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: yeah, i think that's it :) I just can't find an error in my implementation: https://gist.github.com/3098896 If you have a time and  desire to check it out, i would be extremely greatful (the problem is that this query returns completely bad `comments_count` number)

Comment: I think that is because the commentable_id is part of a polymorphic design and you would need to return any targets that are article and where the ID matches. Check your database to see if there are many other things other than Article in a target or source field. So it would basically also match any other model that happens to have the same ID.

Comment: Oh right, i've completely forgot about that, now it's working :) Thank you VERY much // solution in question post

Answer (score 2):

For Rails 4+

You should use something like this:

```
Article.select("articles.*, COUNT(commentable_id) as comments_count")
                    .joins("LEFT JOIN comments AS comments ON comments.commentable_id = articles.id")
                    .group("comments.commentable_id")
                    .order("comments_count DESC")
                    .where("commentable_type = 'Article'")
                    .limit(5)
```

Comment: And how does it differ from the solution posted in the original question ?